# Apache Airflow "greedy" DAG execution

Tags: airflow

**Situation**:
We have a DAG (daily ETL process) with 20 tasks. Some tasks are independent and most have a dependency structure.

**Problem**:
When an independent task fails, Airflow stops the whole DAG execution and marks it as failed.

**Question**:
Would it be possible to force Airflow to keep executing the DAG as long as all dependencies are satisfied? This way one failed independent task would not block the whole execution of all the other streams.

It's seems like such a trivial and fundamental problem, I was really surprised that nobody else has an issue with that behaviour. (Maybe I'm just missing something)

Comment: Does sound like a bug. Are you on the latest version of Airflow (1.8.2)?

Comment: No, we are on 1.8.0. I should have thought about it. Glad to hear that is not the expected behaviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the trigger rules for each individual operarors.

All operators have a trigger_rule argument which defines the rule by which the generated task get triggered. The default value for trigger_rule is all_success and can be defined as “trigger this task when all directly upstream tasks have succeeded”. All other rules described here are based on direct parent tasks and are values that can be passed to any operator while creating tasks:

```
all_success: (default) all parents have succeeded
all_failed: all parents are in a failed or upstream_failed state
all_done: all parents are done with their execution
one_failed: fires as soon as at least one parent has failed, it does not wait for all parents to be done
one_success: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does not wait for all parents to be done
```